# Dart: How to access a class attribute of an object inside another class? (Nested Class)

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I have these two classes MyTask, MyGroup. how can i access MyTask attributes in a list of MyGroup? Please help.
I want to access individual MyTask items in the list of class.
For Instance I create an object of MyGroup as ABC. Now I want to set the value for currentTask of ABC. What should I do to access and set taskName,dueTime etc.

```
 
class MyTask {
  String taskName;
  Timestamp dueTime;
  String member;
  bool completed;

//constructor
  MyTask({this.taskName, this.dueTime, this.member, this.completed});
}

class MyGroup {
  String groupId;
  String groupName;
  String groupAdmin;
  List<String> groupMembers;
  Timestamp groupCreated;
  List<MyTask> currentTask;

  MyGroup({
    this.groupId,
    this.groupName,
    this.groupAdmin,
    this.groupMembers,
    this.groupCreated,
    this.currentTask,
  });
}

MyGroup ABC=MyGroup(groupId: 'xyz',currentTask:[____________]);
```

What to put in the blank?

Comment: More code is needed. Show what you have been trying so far.

Comment: @Daniel please check now if its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `currentTask` is a List of **Objects**, If you want to give it a primitive value, you must assign objects of the same Type to it

like this:

```
 MyGroup ABC=MyGroup(groupId: 'xyz',currentTask:[MyTask(taskName:'taskName1',dueTime:timestampObject1,member:'1',completed:true), MyTask(taskName:'taskName2',dueTime:timestampObject2,member:'2',completed:false)]);
```

Comment: this is not exactly the answer to my question but it kind of gave a small hint,

Comment: At first the question was not clear, in any case I understand what you mean, I will amend my answer